# Trying to rename a file in a folder (based on a string within the filename)

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there I am trying to create a Sub where I find a file in a folder with the name containing a specific phrase like "test_file" and rename it with a different name/extension. I have the following code that doesn't seem to work: (Also I don't know how to search for a specific string within a filename and execute the renaming according to that)

```
Sub ReName()

Dim myFile As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim mVal As String

mVal = "_12345678_" 'test string'

myPath = "C:\Users\bf91955\Desktop\testfolder\" 'folder path'
myFile = Dir(pathname & "*test_file*") 'real file name is 2222_test_test_file.xlsx'
myFile = myPath & myFile

NewName = "new_test_file & mVal & .xlsx" 'save it as .xlsx and with the new filename including myVal'

Name myFile As myPath & NewName 'rename

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I get "Path File Access Error" if I put the path as `"C:\Users\bf91955\Desktop\testfolder\"` if I forego the `"\"' in the end of the path then I get "Run-time error "53": File not found"

Comment: Have rolled back to original question as updating the code to @Toms code makes it look like there was no question.... i.e. your code that doesn't seem to work did work because it was Toms code... or something like that.  Either way we need to see what the problem was and what the answer was so it can help other people down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the comments you had a couple of errors

```
Sub ReName()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim mVal As String

    mVal = "_12345678_" 'test string'

    myPath = "C:\Users\bf91955\Desktop\testfolder\" 'folder path'
    '' You weren't referencing MyPath here - guessing copy and paste error
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*test_file*") 'real file name is 2222_test_test_file.xlsx'
    myFile = myPath & myFile

    '' This was passing the variable as part of the string
    newname = "new_test_file" & mVal & ".xlsx" 'save it as .xlsx and with the new filename including myVal'

    Name myFile As myPath & newname 'rename

End Sub
```

Comment: Valid point, but I still get "File not found" as it doesn't find the file based on a fragment of the full file name. Like the real name of the file is '2222_test_test_file.xlsx'' but I'd need the script to identify and then rename the file based on the fragment 'test_file' and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Check that your path is correct. Is the user really `bf91955` and is the casing of the path correct?

Comment: it is correct indeed, copied straight from the file explorer, funny thing is the macro now renamed the folder not the file lol

Comment: Also, I just noticed if you copied and pasted my code above - I had left the file to find as 'invoice' (what I had in my folder) I've updated it back to `test_file` for you.

Comment: I added a '\' at the end of myPath and now it works :) It renamed the folder not the file before haha. Thank you so much for the help! So if the string is inbetween **'s then the script only searches for that part correct?

Comment: Don't know why it's missing it there as it is in your `myPath` variable. Odd. Yes the `*` are wildcards so it searches for any file that matches a name with `test_file` in the middle